# How does TikTok stream videos in android or how to reduce start time of video in ExoPlayer?

Tags: android-studio, video-streaming, exoplayer2.x

I'm developing an app where I want to stream video from URL. I'm currently using ExoPlayer for streaming and it is working fine but it has a delay of around 5 seconds before the video loads and starts playing. Is there any way to reduce this start time or some way like how TikTok streams their videos on the go. There's no lag involved in TikTok. Could anyone give some workaround for this?

Comment: try this https://bambuser.com/docs/playback/android-player/

Comment: Is there a way to achieve it using ExoPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite a newbie with exoplayer, but I have learnt this:

1. I assume you are using a recyclerview to load a lot of videos.
2. And also that you are playing the video via a url.

WHAT YOU CAN DO:
a. the solution is to precache the video before it even appears on the screen. for example, whilst the video at position 0 is playing, you precache and prebuffer position 1.

Hence, you always precache/prebuffer getAdapterPosition() + 1;

This makes exoplayer load the url even before you get to the video.